# WH_CALLWNDPROC and WH_CALLWNDPROCRET is sometime not matched

Tags: winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I used `SetWindowsHookEx` to install a hook procedure for monitoring the message processing. The hook types are `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET`. But I found that sometimes the calling of hook procedures for `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET` was not matched such as when calling the `CreateWindowExW` function. I want to know why. Is there someone who can help me? I would appreciate your answer.

Comment: Maybe another program has hooked one of the messages and isn't always passing it to `CallNextHookEx`.